# Is it possible to have wasm-bindgen ignore certain public functions in an impl?

Tags: rust

Is it possible to have wasm-bindgen ignore (not produce bindings for) certain public functions in an impl?  I have an impl for which I want some public functions to have bindings, but other public functions for which I don't want bindings.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can use multiple `impl` blocks and add `#[wasm_bindgen]` selectively.

```
impl Foo {
    // pub fns internal to library
}

#[wasm_bindgen]
impl Foo {
    // pub fns to export to JS
}
```